# request.getHeader returning a null value in a jsp page

Tags: java, http-headers, httprequest, httpresponse

I have written a filter to add some header values to Response object.

The doFilter is setting some header value as shown below

```
public void doFilter(final ServletRequest req, final ServletResponse res, final FilterChain filterChain)
            throws IOException, ServletException 
            {   

        final HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        final HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;

        response.setHeader("X-FRAME-OPTIONS", "SAMEORIGIN");    

        filterChain.doFilter(req, res);     

    }
```

Filter mapping is `"/*"`.

I have index.jsp page as welcome page and this is the only page in my application. I am trying to read the header value set in above method.

My index.jsp is

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@page import="java.util.*" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Hello world</title>
</head>
<body>

<%
    out.println("<br/><br/>XFRAME"+request.getHeader("X-FRAME-OPTIONS"));
%>
<br/>
</body>
</html>
```

I am getting Null output in the page. I could not get how I got null value if the value is set to "SAMEORIGIN".

```
XFRAMEnull
```

can any one help on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's simple, you have added an attribute in the `HttpServletResponse` headers and expect to read it from the `HttpServletRequest` headers. That doesn't work that way.

What you need to understand is the HTTP Protocol. The `HttpServletRequest` is the request coming from the client side to the server while the `HttpServletResponse` is the response of data and streams coming from the server and translated back to client message (rendered by the browser).

Each headers from either the request/response has information necessary for the server to know what it receives, how to translate the received data and what response to return. Hence why the `HttpServletRequest.getHeaders()` will almost never be identical to `HttpServletResponse.getHeaders()` as each of the request/response conforms to the HTTP request/response protocols.

Also, you can never expect to populate a response and magically appear on the request.

I hope this helps.

Comment: You can't. One way is to get the session from the `HttpServletRequest`, add your parameter there, and retrieve is from the session using `session.getAttribute()` method.

Comment: @BuhakeSindi: why use the session to store a request-scoped attribute? Use the request.

Comment: @JB Nizet, that's because there are no `setHeader()` methods on `HttpServletRequest`. Besides, I know it's not a good solution, that was my quick-solution "fix". :)

Comment: My point is; rather than doing `session.setAttribute()` in the filter and `session.getAttribute()` in the JSP, why not do `request.setAttribute()` in the filter and `request.getAttribute()` in the JSP. The header is for the current request only, so it shouldn't be stored in the session, but in the request.

Comment: Thanks. It would be great if you can tell me how to check response.setHeader has been executed properly in my filter

Comment: @JBNizet. I want to set the header to response and check if it is added successfully. It would be great if you can tell me, how to check my program is working properly or not.

Comment: @JB Nizet, agreed, one could do that too. User 222, follow what JB Nizet said. :)

Comment: Generally, write tests to check your programs functionality, search for junit. `response.getHeader(java.lang.String name)` is what you are looking for.

Comment: @MichelFeldheim. My server is tomcat. I cannot find response.getheader method in it.

Comment: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html

Comment: @MichelFeldheim: read the javadoc. There is no `getHeader()` in HttpServletResponse. I agree about unit tests, though.

Comment: Oh, you are right. Could use `boolean containsHeader(java.lang.String name)` : "Returns a boolean indicating whether the named response header has already been set."